# Строка содержит не меньше 2 разных символов из списка

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Вот набор символов `[!@#$%^&*?]`, в строке должно быть не меньше двух разных

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```txt
^.*?([!@#$%^&*?]).*?(?!\1)[!@#$%^&*?].*$
```

Пример на JS

```js
const reg = /^.*?([!@#$%^&*?]).*?(?!\1)[!@#$%^&*?].*$/gm;
var str = `строка содержит ! и содержит второй %
строка содержит 2 одинаковых символа подряд @@
строка не содержит символы
строка % содержит только один символ
строка содержит аж три символа %%?
!!`;
console.log(str.match(reg));
```

`^` - начало строки
`.*?` - 0 и более любых символов, вопросительный знак в данном случае смягчает квантификатор `*`, т.е. до ближайшего подходящего символа из следующей части выражения:

```js
const str = "текст % с повторяющимся % знаком % для примера";
const reg1 = /^.*%/gm;
const reg2 = /^.*?%/gm;
console.log(str.match(reg1) + "\n" + str.match(reg2));
```

`([!@#$%^&*?])` - один символ из вашего набора захватываем в группу
`.*?`
`(?!\1)` - негативный просмотр вперед, что следующий символ не равен уже захваченному в группу
`[!@#$%^&*?]` - символ из шаблона кроме того, который есть в группе
`.*$` - ноль и более любых символов до конца строки

Comment: Также можно так написать ^.*?[!@#$%^&*?]{2,}.*$, только это не правильно, пропускает такую строку !!, а должны быть по крайней мере 2 разных символа,  то есть !@, !!@ и т. д.

Comment: @firet Ваш пример подходит на 2 и более подряд идущих символа из шаблона. Сонный не дочитался условия, исправил.